# android webview when resume reload page

Tags: android, webview

I have something like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private WebView mWebView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);

    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    mWebView.loadUrl("http://kwiatkowski.co/");

    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(mWebView.canGoBack()) {
        mWebView.goBack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Everything works only on the target site will be dynamic content and charts. How to make an application to reload page when you restore or I will come in application?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use onResume void to make stuff when resuming app.

```
@Override
  public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mWebView.reload();
  }
```

It will reload webview when resume.

Answer (score 1):

You can use mWebView.reload() to reload the page.